# Perform thresholding in nltk.FreqDist

Tags: python, nltk

I'd like to have my top k frequent words in my FreqDist. Or words that has a freq > p.

How do I do this?

After viewing the [doc](http://nltk.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/api/nltk.probability.FreqDist-class.html), I didn't find anything like `threshold` or `cut`. Also, the freq() function can only be called for each individual bin.

Of course I can write ad-hoc code like

```
[(x,f) for x in FreqDist.samples if FreqDist.freq(x) > p]
```

but it doesn't look elegant.

Comment: Why is that not elegant? I would just write `[x for x in FreqDist if FreqDist[x] > p]` or `[(x, f) for (x, f) in FreqDist.items() if f > p]`

Comment: As @taleinat suggested below, the sorting stuff has been already calculated internally so anything that does that again is deemed as un-elegant, from my part.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [docs](http://nltk.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/api/nltk.probability.FreqDist-class.html) you mentioned, `FreqDist`'s dict-like methods (`keys()`, `items()`, etc.) return samples and/or their frequencies sorted in decreasing order of frequency. So you could use code such as below to filter out only samples with high enough frequencies:

```
above_p = []
for (x, f) in FreqDist.iteritems():
    if not f > p:
        break
    above_p.append((x, f))
```

Or the one-liner:

```
from itertools import takewhile
above_p = [(x, f) for (x, f) in takewhile(lambda x, f: f > p, FreqDist.iteritems())]
```

As for the top k:

```
top_k = FreqDist.items()[:k]
```

Or:

```
from itertools import islice
top_k = list(islice(FreqDist.iteritems(), k))
```

Comment: Cool. I didn't notice that before. And what I did notice is the `FreqDist.plot()` has an internal sort mechanism.